# Find the maximum value in a 2D matrix (recursively)

Tags: c, recursion, matrix

I'm struggling to find the error in my code, I'm trying to find the maximum value in my 2D matrix, in a certain row. Can you help me locate where my logic fails?

```
int maxInRowmaxInRow(int mtx[][N], int row, int cols);
int main()
{
    int mtx[][N] = { {8,1,2,6,7},{1,8,3,9,6},{4,5,-5,1,8},{1,2,3,4,5},{5,4,3,5,3} };
    printf("%d", maxInRow(mtx, 1,N));
    getch();
}

int maxInRow(int mtx[][N], int row, int cols)
{
    int possibleMax = maxInRow(mtx, row, cols - 1);
    if (cols == 0) return mtx[row][cols];

    int max = mtx[row][cols - 1];
    max = (max < maxInRow(mtx, row, cols - 1)) ? possibleMax : max;
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Calling `maxInRow` twice is quite inefficient. Use a variable to receive the result.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I've edited.

Comment: You're still doing it. I edited your code.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Well, that is how I know how to do it. Got a better idea?

Comment: You are only checking the first row, not the entire matrix.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I want to check a certain row only. suddenly the edit you made, made it work. and its kinda weird to me that it works :/ my logic was correct.

Comment: Then adapt your title: the title wants to search the whole matrix.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Okay thanks, I understood now with the debugger how it all works.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I rolled back to the previous version. Your edit did not just correct minor flaws. If you have an answer, write one. We are not supposed to edit the question to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the recursion termination case in the wrong order.  You're also do two recursions instead of one.  Simplifying your code:

```
int maxInRow(int mtx[][N], int row, int cols)
{
    if (cols == 0) return mtx[row][cols];

    int possibleMax = mtx[row][cols - 1];

    int sublistMax = maxInRow(mtx, row, cols - 1);

    int max = (sublistMax > possibleMax) ? sublistMax : possibleMax;

    return max;
}

int main()
{
    int mtx[][N] = {{8,1,2,6,7}, {1,8,3,9,6}, {4,5,-5,1,8}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {5,4,3,5,3}};

    printf("%d\n", maxInRow(mtx, 1, N));
}
```