# Find max value in multidimensional array recursively

Tags: c

I'm studying an algorithm to recursively find the highest value in a multidimensional array (of any size). But it is not working properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int N = 5;

int maxInRow(int matrix[][N], int row, int cols)
{
    if (cols == 0){
        return matrix[row][cols];
    }

    int maxCandidate = matrix[row][cols - 1];

    int maxSublist = maxInRow(matrix, row, cols - 1);

    int max = (maxSublist > maxCandidate) ? maxSublist : maxCandidate;

    return max;
}

int main()
{
    int mtx[5][5] = {{8,1,2,6,7}, {1,80,3,9,6}, {4,5,5,1,8}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {5,4,3,5,300}};

    printf("%d\n", maxInRow(mtx, 1, N-1));
}
```

It should return 300, but it returns 80. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the maximum value in a 2D matrix (recursively)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753296/find-the-maximum-value-in-a-2d-matrix-recursively)

Comment: What you have done is to find out maximum value of a particular row and NOT the max value of the matrix. And in main function you input row  index 1(i.e. the 2nd row) ,so it yields result 80 (the max value of 2nd row). You input N-1 in cols which is wrong and would not consider the last value of the given row in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is to find out maximum value of a particular row and NOT the max value of the multidimensional arrays. To get the maximum value of whole arrays , need to recursively compare all items of all the rows.

Here is one of the way to achieve this(code below)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int N = 5;

int maxInRow(int matrix[][N], int row, int cols)
{
    if (cols == 0 ){
        if(row==1) {
            // the last element of the matrix
            return matrix[0][0];
        }
        else{
            // Comparing all items of row is done, begin next row
            row--;
            cols=N;
        }
    }

    int maxCandidate = matrix[row-1][cols - 1];

    int maxSublist = maxInRow(matrix, row, cols - 1);

    int max = (maxSublist > maxCandidate) ? maxSublist : maxCandidate;

    return max;
}


int main()
{
    int mtx[5][5] = {{8,1,2,6,7}, {1,80,3,9,6}, {4,5,5,1,8}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {5,4,3,5,300}};

    printf("%d\n", maxInRow(mtx, N, N));
}
```